# Alignment in radiobuttonlist, text and pictures are offset

Tags: .net, html, css

[image: Image of the offset problem]

So this is what I get when I try to make a radiobuttonlist in vertical mode without any settings, could someone help me get everything aligned? Feels like i tried everything...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="selectionbuttonlist" 
                     runat="server" 
                     RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                     OnDataBound="selectionbuttonlist_DataBound" 
                     AutoPostBack="true" 
                     RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <asp:ListItem Value="All" Selected="True">
        Allt
    </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="A">
        <img src="../Images/PlanCategoryGeneral.gif" align="absmiddle" />
        Allmänt
    </asp:ListItem>
</RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: I suggest you to add code which generate this.

Comment: I could absolutley use css, I just cant get it to work! Must be missing something!

Comment: Try this, and you can also add `css` tag to your question.

Comment: So you want a vertically aligned RadioButtonList? Assuming you've tried setting `RepeatDirection="Vertical"`? Also, the closing tag here should be `</asp:RadioButtonList>` rather than `</RadioButtonList>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update (misunderstood the question at first, see comment below):

Have you seen [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396439/radio-checkbox-alignment-in-html-css)? It is not exactly the same situation, but pretty close. You should be able to do this by giving your elements a CSS class, then styling that to remove any margins and align it to for instance `middle` or `bottom` (like `vertical-align:middle`).

If this does not work, you might want to try vertically aligning to center, then adding some margin-distance to the top until the elements are positioned where you want them.

Note: You might have to use the type `<asp:RadioButton CssClass="YourClass" />` to do this though; I'm not quite sure if it will work directly on an `<li>` element.

*My previous answer:*

I haven't tested this, but the following seems logical, and seems to be supported by the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatdirection.aspx) (changed "horizontal" to "vertical"):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="selectionbuttonlist" 
                 runat="server" 
                 RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                 OnDataBound="selectionbuttonlist_DataBound" 
                 AutoPostBack="true" 
                 RepeatLayout="Flow">

    (...)
</RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: I still want it horizontal, the problem is that the parts of the radiobuttonlist arent aligned.

Comment: The SO-question link did it... changed my css accordingly, which did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

The code which i used to fix the alignment:

```
  input[type=radio] {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    *overflow: hidden;
}
    input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    *overflow: hidden;
}
```