# html radio button same style in all browsers

Tags: css, html, radio-button

How can I get an input type="radio" the same style in all browsers. I am trying to get 3 radio buttons from left to right accross the page with the radio button and text centered in all IE9, Chrome, and FF using css. I am using all diffferent types or vertical align and padding which works on some but browsers but not all.

```
<input class="text-bottom" type="radio" value="1"  name="ProcessingComplete">Works in FF & Chrome
<input class="middle" type="radio" value="1"  name="ProcessingComplete">Works in IE
<input class="top" type="radio" value="1"  name="ProcessingComplete">Works in FF & Chrome

.middle
{
vertical-align: middle;
}
.top
{
vertical-align: top;
}
.text-bottom
{
vertical-align:text-bottom;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, as I said I was using vertical align and playing around with the padding but unfortunately I could not get padding to make any real difference

Comment: Yeah, that's rough. If it's really important, you might want to consider replacing the radio buttons with your own custom elements as described [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/accessible_custom_designed_checkbox_radio_button_inputs_styled_css_jquery/) (among many other places).

Comment: @showdev I am getting a 403 Forbidden when trying your link. Unfortunately I am just trying to style someone elses code from an MVC project so not sure if I can change the radio buttons to custom elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Dario on [Radio/checkbox alignment in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396439/radio-checkbox-alignment-in-html-css), try this:

```
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-top: -1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also, keep in mind it is best practice to wrap your radio button labels using the `<label>` tag.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/wCykt/).