# how to align radio buttons?

Tags: html, css

```css
#radio1,
#radio2 {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="konk" id='radio1' value="abc">Dady
<input type="radio" name="konk" id='radio2' value="abc">Oliva
```

I tried on jsfiddle and using `vertical-align:top` - buttons are is perfectly `middle` aligned with text.

In my files (localhost and remote) code is the same, but it's impossible to get middle alignement , using any of the css options `top - middle - bottom`.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396439/radio-checkbox-alignment-in-html-css

Comment: No way to answer this. The sizing of the radio buttons depends entirely on how a particular browser renders them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap inputs in one parent element and then use `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on parent, also remove margin from inputs.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
input {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="radio" name="konk" id='radio1' value="abc">Dady
  <input type="radio" name="konk" id='radio2' value="abc">Oliva
</div>
```